# SWT Button: setSelection(true) not working if SWT.READ_ONLY

Tags: java, eclipse, button, widget, swt

I have a matrix of `SWT.TOGGLE` buttons, which are representing some toggle activators on my application.

The idea is display them toggled (pressed) if they are stored as activated, but to be `SWT.READ_ONLY` because this screen has only display purposes and must be non interactive.

The problem is that if I add `SWT.READ_ONLY` to the button, then `setSelection(true)` is not working and all the buttons where I'm calling `setSelection(true)` appear non toggled.

How can we deal with this?

```
Button button = new Button(column, SWT.TOGGLE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
button.setSelection(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SWT.READ_ONLY` is not a valid style for Button, you will get undefined behaviour by specifying it. You can only use the styles listed in the Javdoc for the individual control.

In the current implementation of SWT `SWT.READ_ONLY` has the same value as `SWT.PUSH` so you are effectively using `SWT.TOGGLE | SWT.PUSH` which is expressly forbidden. The implementation is probably choosing to implement `SWT.PUSH` which is why `setSelection` doesn't work.

The only way to stop events from a button is `setEnabled(false)` but this will gray out the value.

So you probably want to use some other way to display these settings.